# I cannot ping a specific external IP through some machines inside the GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ping, external-ip

I have several servers configured in one instance.
I'm having problems accessing a certain external IP where only a few of my machines can ping. other machines do not.
I looked at the firewall rules and I have no ping block, let alone the IP in question.
Does anyone know how I can validate if the lock is within my instance?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any VPC confgured within your GCP ? if so, could you please check all the routes and default gateways of this. Will be great if you can check also VPC firewall rules if they are present.